# adding a number variable with a string

Tags: linux, bash, variables, string

I'm asking the user to enter a number and if the number is greater than 2 then I like to add the string  `-n` to that number. Here's my code:

```
read -p "Enter a number " result_sort
if [ $result_sort >2 ]; then

   result_sort = $result_sort + " -n"

fi

echo "$result_sort"
```

I'm getting the error: `command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
read -p "Enter a number " result_sort
if [ $result_sort -gt 2 ]; then

   result_sort=$(echo "$result_sort -n")

fi

echo "$result_sort"
```

There were two mistakes:

1. The `test` utility (`[`) you used doesn't accept `<` and `>` as greater and less. Those characters are redirection characters (see [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)) in the shell. Your statement in the if clause is always true, even if `$result_sort` is less than 2. You are writing the result of that command `[ $result_sort ]` to a file called `2`.
2. The concatenation of two strings cannot be done in your way.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
result_sort=`echo "${result_sort} -n"`
```

there should be no space between the result_sort and the "=" sign.  In your case because of the space, it identifies result_sort as a command and tries to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in BASH:

```
read -p "Enter a number " result_sort

((result_sort>2)) && result_sort+=" -n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The result can be accomplished simply by concatenating the string values of the variables:

```
read -p "Enter a number " result_sort

[ "$result_sort" > 2 ] && 
result_sort="${result_sort}-n"

echo "$result_sort"
```

**brace protecting** the variable can prevent ambiguity. Also using the arithmetic comparison given by anubhava can protect against users entering something other than numbers.